# How to assign command output to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to assign the ouput of the following command to a variable in shell:

```
${arr2[0]} | rev | cut -c 9- | rev
```

For example:

```
mod=${arr2[0]} | rev | cut -c 9- | rev 
echo $mod
```

The above method is not working: the output is blank.

I also tried:

```
mod=( "${arr2[0]}" | rev | cut -c 9- | rev )
```

But I get the error:

```
34: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
line 34: `  mod=( "${arr2[0]}" | rev | cut -c 9- | rev )   '
```

Comment: What's in `$arr2`? How do you assign it? How exactly is it not working (error message, expected vs. actual output)?

Comment: in $arr2[0] i have a long string and i am trimming last 8 characters.  if i echo ${arr2[0]} | rev | cut -c 9- | rev, i get what i want.  but i want to assign the outcome to a variable.  right now echo $mod give me blank, nothing.  I assign by: arr2=($line)

Comment: I GOT IT,  mod=$(echo "${arr2[0]}" | rev | cut -c 9- | rev )   
                 echo "****:"$mod

Comment: @fali You should submit and accept your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mod=$(echo "${arr2[0]}" | rev | cut -c 9- | rev )   
echo "****:"$mod
```

or

```
mod=`echo "${arr2[0]}" | rev | cut -c 9- | rev`   
echo "****:"$mod
```

Comment: accept this answer so new people do not try to answer

Comment: I can't accept my own answer. "It say i can't accept my own answers in 18 hrs."

Comment: You are right. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer tells you have to wait 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

To add an **explanation** to [your correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440594/45375):

You had to combine your variable assignment with a **[command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`var=$(...)`)** to capture the (stdout) output of your command in a variable.

By contrast, your original command used just **`var=(...)` - no `$` before the `(` - which is used to create *arrays***<sup>[1]</sup>, with each token inside `( ... )` becoming its own array element - which was clearly not your *intent*.

As for **why your original command *broke***:

The **tokens inside `(...)` are subject to the usual [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)** and therefore the usual quoting requirements.

Thus, in order **to use `$` and the so-called shell *metacharacters* (`|`  `&` `;` `(` `)` `<` `>` `space` `tab`) as *literals*** in your array elements, you must ***quote* them**, e.g., by prepending `\`.

All these characters - except `$`, `space`, and `tab` - cause a syntax error when left unquoted, which is what happened in your case (you had unquoted `|` chars.)

<sup>[1] In `bash`, and also in `ksh` and `zsh`. The POSIX shell spec. doesn't support arrays at all, so this syntax will *always* break in POSIX-features-only shells.</sup>